# Format Moment.js am/pm to include periods/dots

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm running into a small formatting issue with moment's `a` input.

a/A will return AM/am PM/pm but is there a way to format this to include periods?

I.E. **a.m. p.m.** it's a format change that is important to the client and I haven't been able to find the fix with moment's documentation

I've tried

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    meridiem : {
        am : 'a.m.',
        AM : 'A.M.',
        pm : 'p.m.',
        PM : 'P.M.'
    }
});
```

With no success

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you used to customize the meridiem applies to versions < 1.6.0. You should provide a function in newer versions to update meridiem. Please see [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/) for more info:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  meridiem: function(hour, minute, isLowerCase) {
    if (hour < 12) {
      return 'a.m.';
    } else {
      return 'p.m.';
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following moment [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/) you can have the following:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  meridiem: function (hour, minute, isLowercase) {
    if( hour >= 12 )
      return isLowercase ? 'p.m.' : 'P.M.';
    else
      return isLowercase ? 'a.m.' : 'A.M.';
  }
});
console.log(moment().hour(1).format('HH:mm a'));
console.log(moment().hour(15).format('HH:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

As stated in the documentation, from moment version **1.6.0**

> `Locale#meridiem` should be a callback function that returns the correct string based on hour, minute, and upper/lowercase.

While on version before **1.6.0**:

> `Locale#meridiem` was a map of upper and lowercase versions of am/pm.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @user4040648 answer here is how you can implement it in es6

```
    moment.updateLocale('en', {
      meridiem(hour, minute, isLowerCase) {
          return hour < 12 ? 'a.m.' : 'p.m.';
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The meridiem map was in versions 1.5.x and below, after 1.6.0 the meridiem is a function that returns the value (see [link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/)).