# Format longDateFormat in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs

I asked an earlier question about formatting AM/PM via Moment.js meridiem function. BTW I am using version 2.9

I was successful in adding periods to the AM/PM input and applying lowercase by using the this

```
moment.locale('en', {
    meridiem: function(hour, minute, isLower) {
       if (hour < 12) {
          return isLower ? 'a.m.' : 'A.M.';
       } else {
          return isLower ? 'p.m' : 'P.M.';
       }
    }
});
```

Now I have run into an issue where I need to do the same type of formatting for a `longDateFormat` string.

The string is `"h:mm:ss a"` and the time returned would be the current time but with an uppercase **AM/PM**

I need the current time returned but the a input should be formatted **a.m. p.m.**

in the moment docs longDateFormat is an object not a function how would I go about formatting the meridiem here?

********************EDIT****************

Here is an example of my issue.

the meridiem setting is working fine with an h a z input. it is lowercase and has periods.
[image]

the meridiem setting doesn't affect a longDateFormat string. The am/pm is always uppercase with no periods. No matter if I change the meridiem settings I applied initially. How can I change this?

HTML
[image]

```
{{last_update|date:"MMMM d, y 'at' h:mm:ss a"}}.
```

Result
[image]

```
Last updated on July 6, 2016 at 8:25:00 AM.
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer is in your previous question :). If you use [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38204712/4131048) you will always have **a.m./p.m.** lowercase. If you use [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38204793/4131048) you will have **a.m./p.m.** case aware (depends on `a` or `A` in format). Your snippet returns **AM/PM** if you specify `a` in the format and **a.m./p.m.** if you set `A` (inverted default logic)

Comment: Hi @VincenzoC I'm not following you. The longDateFormat is not correct even when the meridiem is set. The longDateFormat a returns an always capital AM PM with no periods

Comment: What happens if you remove `meridiem` customization? In my opinion, you are getting **AM/PM** uppercase because of the ternary operator in your `meridiem` function. When the format contains lowercase `a`, `isLowerCase` is `true`, while when you have uppercase `A`, `isLowerCase` is `false`. Removing the `isLowerCase` check should solve your issue. Maybe you can add a snippet that reproduce your issue to  clarify you question further.

Comment: @VincenzoC I updated the question and posted a couple pictures

Comment: Sorry I can't see the pictures, probably something went bad while uploading. Anyway a code example of your issue would be far better than a screenshot.

Comment: @VincenzoC i put what was in the images in a code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using angular, you have to use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) to take advantage of moment inside directive and filters.

angular-moment provides a `amDateFormat` filter that *Format dates using moment.js format() method* as the docs say.
The following code can help to get what you desire:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.run(function(){
  moment.locale('en', {
    meridiem: function(hour, minute, isLower) {
      if (hour < 12) {
         return isLower ? 'a.m.' : 'A.M.';
      } else {
         return isLower ? 'p.m.' : 'P.M.';
      }
    }
  });
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.last_update = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/0.10.3/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  With angular default date filter: <br/>
  {{last_update|date:"MMMM d, y 'at' h:mm:ss a"}}
  <br/>
  With angular-moment date filter: <br/>
  {{last_update|amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}
  
</div>
```

In your example you are using angular default [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: Thanks so much Vincenzo, just as you replied I realised I was using angulars date format. The angular moment is a great solution. Thanks for your help!