# How can I format time period using moment format?

Tags: javascript, time, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am doing this and works for me

```
const getDate = (date) => {
  return moment(date).
  format('LT').
  replace('AM', 'a.m.').
  replace('PM', 'p.m.');
 };
```

I would like to combine the replace into one line? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This might help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Moment.js am/pm to include periods/dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204436/format-moment-js-am-pm-to-include-periods-dots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could  use `format('h:m a')` which already produces lower case and add the dots using regex capture groups

```js
console.log(moment().format('h:mm a').replace(/(a|p)(m)/,'$1.$2.'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good solution! Note that momentjs provides a way to customize [am/pm](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/), in the suggested dupe there are answers that shows how to get dots in am/pm.