# MomentJS change display of "am" to "a.m."

Tags: momentjs

I have a bit of an odd request from our product owner. He wants us to change the display of the "am" and "pm" to display as "a.m." and "p.m." Ideally, we need to do this in one place so it just handles it everywhere we leverage momentjs.

I've checked the momentJS documentation and it doesn't seem that there's an easy way to specify this in the docs.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Comment: I love that guy. He'll want it unabbreviated next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date with Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js)

Comment: [`updateLocale`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) using the [`meridiem`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/) key is the easy way to get your desired output, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38204436/4131048) an example.